# how to retrieve the word associated with final centroids of k means clustering

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the actual label associated with the final centroids as I want to cluster corpus of words that came from word2vec model then plug the word vectors into the K-means algorithm.

so far searching lots of posts but they only retrieve the centroids, not the corresponding label, for example, I want to know if these many words clustered in the same cluster which word locates in the center of them.

```
# associating each word to its respective clusters
words = list(trained_model.wv.vocab)
w1 = []
for i, word in enumerate(words):  
    w1.append(word + ":" + str(assigned_clusters[i]))
print(w1)
```

for now, I only get the words and its cluster label but I want which of the word belong to center of the cluster

I would be grateful if any suggestion.

Comment: hello, did you tried  model.cluster_centers ?

Comment: I did use lots of tricks to get it but only up to this part rest I do not figure it   
    out.kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1] and from this I can't map it to its respective word @AdForte

Comment: I used the same at least question that is asked a few months before from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660937/get-nearest-point-to-centroid-scikit-learn  but it gives the nearest point which is not even in this cluster closest, _ = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(kmeans_model.cluster_centers_, Z)
print(closest) sorry for my question it is not so clear but I want the nearest points close to each centoids