# How to get the centre point in Kmeans

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, centroid

Below is a sample of the data set that I am using:

```
   id,product,store,revenue,store_capacity,state
    1,Ball,AB,222,1000,CA
    1,Pen,AB,234,1452,WD
    2,Books,CD,543,888,MA
    2,Ink,EF,123,9865,NY
```

Code is below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})

df = pd.read_csv(r'1.csv',index_col=None)
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data = df)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(dummies)
labels = km.predict(dummies)
dummies['cluster_id'] = km.labels_
def distance_to_centroid(row, centroid):
    row = row[['id', 'product', 'store', 'revenue','store_capacity', 'state_AL', 'state_CA', 'state_CH',
       'state_WD', 'country_India', 'country_Japan', 'country_USA']]
    return euclidean(row, centroid)
dummies['distance_to_center0'] = dummies.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[0]),1)

dummies['distance_to_center1'] = dummies.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[1]),1)

dummies['distance_to_center2'] = dummies.apply(lambda r: distance_to_centroid(r,
    km.cluster_centers_[2]),1)

dummies_df = dummies[['distance_to_center0','distance_to_center1','cluster_id']]
test = {0:"Blue", 1:"Red", 2:"Green"}
sns.scatterplot(x="distance_to_center0", y="distance_to_center1", data=dummies_df, hue="cluster_id", palette = test)
```

I need to get the centre of each cluster, Code below is getting `centroid of each element` means what is the distance from each element to the centre point of the cluster

```
centroids  = km.cluster_centers_
centroid_labels = [centroids[i] for i in labels]
centroid_label
```

I want to get the centre point of each cluster

Comment: Isn't the centroid the center of each cluster? Do you mean the closest point to the center? If so, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660937/get-nearest-point-to-centroid-scikit-learn

Comment: @Isma G, means what is the distance from each element to the centre point of the cluster
. Need to have what is the centre point of the each cluster. if there are 5 clusters, 5 centre point

Comment: Those are the centroids!

Comment: @isma G thanks, my bad,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

courtesy @Isma

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=7).fit(dummies)
closest, _ = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(km.cluster_centers_, dummies)
closest
```